# BaseAdapter On Scroll Refresh Data in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, baseadapter

I'm Very new to Java and android... I'm Try to create an ListView using BaseAdapter List being created successfully i have a EditText along with button for each list item but the real problem is when i put some data into editText Field and scroll down to change value of last list item then i go back to the top it refreshes the data to default value it doesn't contain the value which was entered by user before scrolling down[image: This Image is Before Scrolling]
[image: This Image is after scroll - Check first image there is visual changes in update button but once i scroll down and go back to top again it lose all visual change is button]

My BaseAdaper Code

```
    class CoustomAdptr extends BaseAdapter{

    String[] dates;
    Integer[] inventory;
    Integer totalrooms;
    public CoustomAdptr(RoomFragment roomFragment, String[] dates, Integer[] inventory, Integer totalrooms) {
        this.dates = dates;
        this.inventory = inventory;
        this.totalrooms = totalrooms;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dates.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inventory_listview,null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.roomListViewText);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.roomListInventory);
        final Button updateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.roomListViewInventoryUpdateButton);
        if(inventory[i] == 0){
            editText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.SoldOut));
            editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.SoldOutTextColor));
        } else if(inventory[i] < totalrooms){
            editText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.invetory));
            editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.invetoryTextColor));
        } else if(inventory[i] == totalrooms){
            editText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fullInventory));
            editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fullInventoryTextColor));
        }

        editText.setText(String.valueOf(inventory[i]));
        textView.setText(dates[i]);
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //String name = editText.getText().toString();
                //String name1 = dates[i];
                //String name2 = getArguments().getString("room_id");
                updateButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp,0,0,0);
                //updateButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.SoldOut));
                updateButton.setText("Updated");
                updateButton.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Update Inventory Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is How Im Passing Data to My Adapter

```
JSONObject jObj = parentObject.getJSONObject("success");
JSONObject jObj2 = jObj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray arrajson = jObj2.getJSONArray("inventories");
String arrayCount = Integer.toString(arrajson.length());
String[] dates = new String[arrajson.length()];
Integer[] inventory = new Integer[arrajson.length()];
Integer totalrooms = new Integer(jObj2.getInt("total_room"));
for (int i=0; i<arrajson.length();i++){
     JSONObject jsonObject = arrajson.getJSONObject(i);
     dates[i] = jsonObject.getString("date");
     inventory[i] = jsonObject.getInt("inventory");
}
CoustomAdptr coustomAdptr = new CoustomAdptr(RoomFragment.this,dates,inventory,totalrooms);
listView.setAdapter(coustomAdptr);
```

**Help Needed** :- I Want to retain same visible and Value of edittext as users enters on scroll up or down... i hope i was able to explain my problem clearly

Comment: Store the selected state as `boolean`  for every item of the list view , while scrolling up to down or down to up it will seek to `getView()` method , there u check if `isSelected` is true change the state according to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking a button, save it's state in a boolean array or somewhere else. And inside getView method, check if this button was previously clicked or not then setup your view accordingly.

It would be better if you create a model class for rows.